# Удаление логов посредством Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

В классе `ActorDetailsActivity` в методе `onCreate` у меня есть следующий блок кода:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate method was invoked")
```

В *app/build.gradle* файле я имею следующие buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
        debugProguardTest {
            initWith debug
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
        release {
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

И сам файл *proguard-rules.pro* выглядит следующим образом:

```
-printusage ./removed-usaged.txt
-printseeds ./kept-seeds.txt
#-printmapping ./mapping.txt
-optimizationpasses 3
#-dontobfuscate

-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.*

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Также я выключила *R8* в файле *gradle.properties*:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

Однако всё равно после сборки проекта (с buildVariant *debugProguardTest* ) 
вызов метода

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate method was invoked")
```

не был удалён из apk. В Apk Analyzer-e я всё равно вижу строку:

```
const-string v0, "onCreate method was invoked"
```

Почему так происходит? И как всё-таки вырезать Proguard-ом вызов методов `Log.d()` из apk?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827404/proguard-does-not-remove-my-logs/21827596#21827596

Comment: @Olmicron, спасибо, я видела этот ответ, но у меня нет project.properties файла в проекте

Comment: @Olmicron, и я на всякий случай попробовала создать такой файл, содержащий 
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-rules.pro
но всё равно ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Ну нужно ничего создавать. Просто используйте proguard-android-optimize.txt в место proguard-android.txt.

Comment: @Olmicron, кстати, да, кажется, это помогло - заменить proguard-android.txt на proguard-android-optimize.txt в build.gradle файле. Но почему это сработало?

Comment: Отлично. Добавил ответ, там же и небольшое пояснение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте **proguard-android-optimize.txt** в место **proguard-android.txt**, т.к. в *proguard-android.txt* используется *dontoptimize* и *dontpreverify*, что не позволяет удалить лог (помимо прочего).

Comment: Действительно, нашла эти файлы в sdk, всё так и есть) Спасибо огромное!)